# What's the cleanest way to set up an enumeration in Python?

Tags: python, enums, enumeration

I'm relatively new to Python and I was interested in finding out the simplest way to create an enumeration.

The best I've found is something like:

```
(APPLE, BANANA, WALRUS) = range(3)
```

Which sets APPLE to 0, BANANA to 1, etc.

But I'm wondering if there's a simpler way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enums were added in python 3.4 ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/enum.html)).  See [PEP 0435](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/) for details.

If you are on python 2.x, there exists a [backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) on pypi.

```
pip install enum34
```

Your usage example is most similar to the python enum's functional API:

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> MyEnum = Enum('MyEnum', 'APPLE BANANA WALRUS')
>>> MyEnum.BANANA
<MyEnum.BANANA: 2>
```

However, this is a more typical usage example:

```
class MyEnum(Enum):
    apple = 1
    banana = 2
    walrus = 3
```

You can also use an `IntEnum` if you need enum instances to compare equal with integers, but I don't recommend this unless there is a good reason you need that behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this. Although slightly longer, much more readable and flexible.

```
from enum import Enum
class Fruits(Enum):
    APPLE = 1
    BANANA = 2
    WALRUS = 3
```

*Edit : Python 3.4*

Comment: Agreed on that. Python codestyle endorse explicit coding.

Comment: Just use the `Enum` initializer: `Fruits = Enum('Fruits', 'APPLE BANANA WALRUS')`.

Comment: If we wish to have `APPLE=654, BANANA = 980` and so on..?

Comment: @Noob The API supports that too: `Fruits = Enum('Fruits', dict(APPLE=62, BANANA=980))`

Answer (score 1):

Using enumerate

```
In [4]: list(enumerate(('APPLE', 'BANANA', 'WALRUS'),1))
Out[4]: [(1, 'APPLE'), (2, 'BANANA'), (3, 'WALRUS')]
```

The answer by noob should've been like this

```
In [13]: from enum import Enum

In [14]: Fruit=Enum('Fruit', 'APPLE BANANA WALRUS')
```

enum values are distinct from integers.

```
In [15]: Fruit.APPLE
Out[15]: <Fruit.APPLE: 1>

In [16]: Fruit.BANANA
Out[16]: <Fruit.BANANA: 2>

In [17]: Fruit.WALRUS
Out[17]: <Fruit.WALRUS: 3>
```

As in your question using range is a better option.

```
In [18]: APPLE,BANANA,WALRUS=range(1,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ('APPLE', 'BANANA', 'WALRUS')
```

You can create a list of tuples using enumerate to get the desired output.

```
list(enumerate(a, start=1))
[(1, 'APPLE'), (2, 'BANANA'), (3, 'WALRUS')]
```

If you need `'APPLE'` first and then `1`, then you can do the following:

```
[(j, i +1 ) for i, j in enumerate(a)]
[('APPLE', 1), ('BANANA', 2), ('WALRUS', 3)]
```

Also, you can create a dictionary using `enumerate` to get the desired output.

```
dict(enumerate(a, start=1))
{1: 'APPLE', 2: 'BANANA', 3: 'WALRUS'}
```

Comment: @downvoter Please explain the reason for the downvote. This way i can know what i have missed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dict as well:

```
d = {
    1: 'APPLE',
    2: 'BANANA',
    3: 'WALRUS'
}
```